# Remove and rebind method according to screen size?

Tags: jquery

How do you unbind a method? I'm using imagefill; a script that fills a responsive div with an image. All I have to do is bind `.imagefill()` to the desired container like so: `$('.container').imagefill();`

However, what I'm trying to do right now is remove the method when the width of the screen gets too small. Currently I have this:

```
    if ($(window).width() > 651) {
        $('.container').imagefill();
    } else {
        // remove imagefill() method
    }
```

Would there be a way to use the 'unbind' method for it? I've searched elsewhere online but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: Just a heads up - if you're binding events to the window size  events, you may want a debounce/throttle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some plugins have `destroy` method, that you can use to remove instance of pluing on the element:

```
$('#element').popover('destroy') // bootstrap's popover
```

but for those that don't, I think this can work :

```
$.removeData($element.get(0), 'pluginName'); // destroy plugin instance
$element.off('pluginNamespace'); // unbind plugin events 
$element.unbind('.pluginNamespace'); // unbind plugin events
```

more here:

http://ub4.underblob.com/remove-jquery-plugin-instance/

https://api.jquery.com/off/